# How do I segregate values based on the name of the listview item? (An elaborative description)

Tags: java, android, listview

Two listview items ABC and DEF share the same listview. When I give "ABC" as input, it shows up in the listview shared by ABC. But when I give "DEF" as input it shows up in the listview shared by DEF along with "ABC".

I want all "ABC" items to show up in ABC's listview, and "DEF" items in DEF's.

*activity.class:*

```
public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static String st2;
public static String st1;


        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            listItem = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                st2= (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                st1=(String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(st1.equals("ABC"))
{

                        startActivity(newIntent(activity.this,new_activity.class))

 }

if(st2.equals("DEF"))
{

              startActivity(newIntent(activity.this,new_activity.class))

}

            }
        });



        }
```

*new_activity.class*

```
 public static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
 public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String str=edittext.getText().toString();
                        list.add(str);
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(new_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
if(str.equals("ABC"))
{
   if(st1.equals(str))
    {
       listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter); //The first time I give "ABC" as input, it shows up in the listview shared by st1(ABC).
    }
}

if(str.equals("DEF"))
{
      if(st2.equals(str))
       {
               listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);// The second tie I give "DEF" as input, it shows up in the listview shared by st2(DEF), but along with the "ABC" item.
        }
}
}
```

*My strings.xml-*

```
</string>
    <string-array name="items">
        <item>ABC</item>
        <item>DEF</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193554/pies-den @Parker

Comment: Sorry,but I need 20 rep for chatting

Answer (score 0):

If the the list(`List<String> list`) contains both DEF and ABC, it will show up in both lists. The solution is to create 2 variables `List<String> list`. If you can expand a little what DEF ABC stands for, I will give you more detailed answer. Is it literally 'ABC' and 'DEF' or a part of a string? If it's a part, you can filter the list with regex.

Comment: Yes it's literally 'ABC' and 'DEF'. If I give ABC as input, then the 'ABC''s listview should show that string, otherwise 'DEF's listview should show the string. But the problem is that when I give both ABC and DEF as inputs one after the other, both the strings show up in 'DEF's listview.

Comment: Well, if both strings are in the list .contains check will always return true. Explain what is your end goal? A list full of ABCs? What kind of inputs do you expect after ABC, DEF?

Comment: And you don't really have DEF's listview or ABC's listview, you create one adapter and plug the list in before "if" checks.

Comment: Yes, DEF and ABC are two listview items (which share the same listview), and upon opening any of the items it should show the string (ABC or DEF) which is sent as input.

Comment: So you click the item and another view opens? Did you implement onClickListener?  You can get clicked item position and based on what was clicked decide what to do with original `List<String> list`. Say ABC was clicked  then `list.removeIf(s -> s.contains("DEF"))`. Pass the list forward to new Activity